# Template returning value error

Tags: c++, oop, templates

I have this method in class Entity

```
template <class T>
T get_field(const std::string &content, const std::string &field_name)
{
    JSONValue *value = JSON::Parse(content.c_str());
    if (value == NULL)
    {
        LOG(ERROR) << "JSONValue is NULL";
        return NULL;
    }
    if (value->IsObject())
    {
        JSONObject object = value->AsObject();
        std::wstring ws;
        for (int i = 0; i<field_name.length(); i++)
            ws += wchar_t(field_name[i]);
        if (object.find(ws) != object.end())
        {
            if (object[ws]->IsArray())
            {
                return object[ws]->AsArray();
            }
            else if (object[ws]->IsBool())
            {
                return object[ws]->AsBool();
            }
            else if (object[ws]->IsNull())
            {
                return NULL;
            }
            else if (object[ws]->IsNumber())
            {
                return object[ws]->AsNumber();
            }
            else if (object[ws]->IsObject())
            {
                return object[ws]->AsObject();
            }
            else if (object[ws]->IsString())
            {
                return object[ws]->AsString();
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

and I am calling this method like this:

```
e.get_field<std::string>(json, "Name")
```

I know that method should return string in this case so I added `std::string` in `< ... >`. But I get this error:

```
No viable conversion from 'const JSONArray' (aka 'const vector<JSONValue *>') to 'std::__1::basic_string<char>'
```

I know, why am I getting this error. Because I can't return something that is not of type string in this case. If I would call that method like this

```
e.get_field<JSONArray>(json, "numbers");
```

then this will be also error because I can't return string as JSONArray. So, how to prevent this?

Comment: If I say `e.get_field<JSONArray>(json, "numbers");` this is error. Because it can't return bool. So I need to write conversion function? How to write it. Like from json_array_to_string?

Comment: Yes, but point is that I want to create generic function, so that it can return practicly anyone of this types. Is this possible?

Comment: Not like this.  You are attempting to mix a compile time `template` return type with a type that you don't know until runtime (`object[ws]`).

Comment: And how is possible to create such generic function?

Comment: Have a look at boost variant:  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/variant.html

Comment: Better rethink your design. You're going to do different things depending on what type of json data you get, aren't you? Then why have all those different data types run through one code path...